# window - C# Resize Form by Inputting in Textbox

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, textbox, resize

```
private void txtCkInNumOcc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int numocc = int.Parse(txtCkInNumOcc.text);

   if(numocc > 1)
   {
      AddCheckIn checkin = new AddCheckIn();
      checkin.Height = 470;
   }
}
```

I like to resize my form to 470 if the textbox is greater than 1 without buttons.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Forms are never scalars.  Do you mean you want the horizontal dimension to be 470?  And I am not sure what you mean about the textBox being > (1 without buttons)?

Comment: If the value of the textbox is more than 1 then the form will resize to 470.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this.Height` if you need to change the height of the current form

```
private void txtCkInNumOcc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int numocc;

   if(int.TryParse(txtCkInNumOcc.text, out numocc) && numocc > 1)
   {
      this.Height = 470;
   }
}
```